# Is there a canonical way of placing the scoring meeple to signify having gone round the scoring track?

Tags: carcassonne, scoring

Newer versions of *Carcassonne* (or perhaps it's one of the expansions) contain scoring tiles, to track how many times a player's score-keeping meeple has gone round the scoring track, so that 50 or 100 points need to be added to the score the meeple indicates.

Before that, I've seen (and used myself) an alternative way of tracking that: placing the meeple in another position than both feet down. Either balancing on one foot and one hand, balancing on one hand and its head, or lying  flat.

**Is there an established rule of which position indicates what?**

---

*I've always used hand+foot: +50, hand+head: +100, lying flat: +150.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The official, pre-expansion rule to keep track of 50 points was to lay down the scoring meeple like a farmer.**

Start of page 4 of the [official rules (pdf)](https://images.zmangames.com/filer_public/d5/20/d5208d61-8583-478b-a06d-b49fc9cd7aaa/zm7810_carcassonne_rules.pdf):

> Note: if your score passes 50 points, lay down your scoring meeple to show your 50+ points

Of course, any way to mark 50+ or 100+ points that your group agrees on and that can be clearly distinguished from each other is fine.

Comment: FYI: The score-track tiles came with the first expansion: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Carcassonne-Erweiterungen#Ung%C3%BCltig:_1.Erw_in_Vorlage:Anker_Wirtsh%C3%A4user_und_Kathedralen_(1._Erweiterung) (link only in German, sorry).